# Plone 4.1 Custom PAS plugin with paster

Tags: plone

Trying to create custom pas plugin for authentication. Doing this via paster

```
../bin/paster create -t plone_pas abc.xyz
```

now what I'm seeing in when its creates structure it take two dots in namespace and creating two identical dictionaries. structure of my pas product dictionaries is like:

```
abc 
   xyz
   __init__.py
        xyz
        __init__.py
```

why its taking two dots in namespace. Is there something I'm missing here?

first level of xyz dictionaries needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maurita is, of course, correct.

If you use the 'zopeskel' command, you'll actually have validation applied to you package name, and you will be informed about the restriction. Try this:

```
../bin/zopeskel plone_pas abc.xyz
```

You should get a message that tells you that a two-dot name is required for this template. The script should prompt you for a new name and allow you to re-enter something like abc.def.xyz

Answer (score 3):

This is an unfortunate restriction of the plone_pas paster template: it only knows how to create a package structure that is three levels deep.  So you should give a name like abc.def.xyz.

Recommended is calling your package: pas.plugins.meaningfulname.

Comment: Is using zopeskel for creating a custom plone_pas plugin still the way to go?

Comment: Yes, that should still give you a good structure. I am still using ZopeSkel 2.21.2 by the way.